# [buildroot]hciconfig can't open HCI socket error

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, buildroot

I am using buildroot-2014.05 git.It has been cross-compiled to below toolchains.
"ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, not stripped
"

I am getting below error message.

```
# hciconfig 
Can't open HCI socket.: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your kernel is not configured correctly. In your kernel config make sure `CONFIG_BT` and the appropriate configs beneath that are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the corresponding kernel modules are loaded. You should have at least `bluetooth`, `btusb` when running the following:

   lsmod | grep bluetooth
2. If the kernel modules did not show up, try adding them:

   modprobe -vvv bluetooth
   modprobe -vvv btusb
3. If `modprobe` failed, check the files in `/etc/modprobe.d` in cases they are
   black-listed there.